# rxjs catchError import issue for rxjs@6.3.3

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, rxjs, rxjs6

Trying to import catchError for rxjs v6.3.3 but import looks not working. I am getting error while using catch.

Found similar questions but looks none helped me.

**Code:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IWinServices } from './WinServices';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catch } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WinServicesService {

  private _url : string = './assets/Data/WinServicess.json'
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getWinServices() :Observable <IWinServices[]>  {
      return this.http.get<IWinServices[]>(this._url).catch (this.errorHandler);

  }

  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

    return Observable.throw(error.message || "Server Error");
  }
}
```

**Tried Possible solution :** None worked for me

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

**Error:**

> `Property 'catch' does not exist on type Observable<IWinServices[]>'.ts(2339)`
>
> ```
> ERROR in src/app/employee.service.ts(16,52): error TS2339: Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<IEmployee[]>'
> ```

Comment: catchError is to be used as pipeable operator. I don't see you using it anywhere in your code.

Comment: The error you are receiving is because you are using .catch on Observable, that's not possible

Comment: Looks I have used older tutorial, I will to switch newer version using pipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error explains the problem.

> `error TS2339: Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<IEmployee[]>'`

**In rxjs v6+ you no longer chain operators onto the observable call.**

Instead, try this...

Import like the following `import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';`

pipe the `catchError` like this.

```js
return this.http.get<IWinServices[]>(this._url).pipe(
    catchError(() => {
       // error handling logic here
    })
)
```

See this great site for reference.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

Final note: 
Don't use this `import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';` it is not recommended as it is not a scoped import.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't know where to import catchError from. it is in `rxjs/operators`!

Comment: Yes, please see my answer. I mention where to import it from.